# Simple(i think) XPages issue with Partial Refresh

Tags: xpages

I copied this code from another question just to have something simple that should work and it still isn't working.  Whether I use IE, Firefox or Safari this code will not do the partial refresh.  Is there some global setting I need to set or am I missing something very simple?  Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup1">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="One"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Two"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Three"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelRadioVal" rendered="#{javascript:!context.getUserAgent().isIE()}" />
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelRadioVal" rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()}" />
</xp:radioGroup>
<xp:panel id="panelRadioVal">
    <xp:inputText value="#{javascript:getComponent('radioGroup1').getSubmittedValue()}" />
</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want `.getValue()` instead of `.getSubmittedValue()`

That will show the Item in the inputText.